# Review Queues Urgent Indication Doesn't Clear Properly

Tags: bug

When a review queue gets several questions waiting to be reviewed the system adds a red indication to the queues dropdown menu at the top of the page.  However, once this queue has been cleared the indication does not go away, at least a lot of the time.

I check the review queues regularly throughout my work day, so it can be pretty annoying to see queues marked as needing attention but in reality the queue has already been cleared.

I haven't browser tested this bug, I use Chrome mostly.  As a quick test I tried clearing my cache but that didn't work.  I also tried logging out and signing back in.

Here is a picture to explain what I'm talking about.

[image]

I tagged this question with `bug`, is there something else I should do to have this looked into?

Comment: Weird, I never had this problem. And I'm also every day in the review queues, multiple times. The red dot disappears.

Comment: That is weird.  I've always had this issue but it was rare because Suggested Edits and First Posts rarely get that far behind.  But now that I can Close Votes I almost always have a red dot.

Comment: Did you skip a few items? Maybe those are triggering the dot (they shouldn't).

Comment: No, I have only ever skipped a couple questions in all of my reviews.

Comment: I've seen this bug too few times

Comment: Finally, another person that has seen it :)